# Rails production asset compress and integration

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Fast Example,

lets say, i have this js file, test.coffee

```
alert 'test!'
```

my goal is,

I dont want this code to be loaded in every pages

so i manually included where i want,

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'test'%>
```

but the tragedy happens in production mode,

this `test.coffee` is not minified in production mode!

I want this code to be minified, but it should not integrate and minified to `application.js`, because i don't want this code be loaded in every pages.

How can i solve this dilemma?

Answer (score 0):

You are having this issue because rails by default doesn't precompile file with the `coffee` extension. You should be able to solve this issue be prepending the `.js` extension so your file should look like this:

`test.js.coffee`

Straight from the rails docs:

> When using asset precompilation, you will need to ensure that your controller assets will be precompiled when loading them on a per page basis. By default .coffee and .scss files will not be precompiled on their own. See Precompiling Assets for more information on how precompiling works.

Note:

There's a mechanism in rails that allows you to "inject" javascript at runtime.

Typically you would define a `yield :javascripts` in your app layout.
And add content to this yield using:

```
<% content_for :javascripts do %>
  <%= script_tag :test %> # Content here will be yielded
<% end %>
```

This allows you to define your javascript at the bottom page while injecting page specific assets.